# Terraform does not remember several ElasticBeanstalk settings

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an environment created with the resource [aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_environment). Unfortunately, Terraform shows me with each `plan` and `apply` that several settings have to be added, including the VPCId.

I got the settings using the AWS CLI [describe-configuration-settings](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/describe-configuration-settings.html) and they match what I specified, but Terraform says the settings need to be re-added each time.

I have tried both this statement

```
  setting {
    name      = "VPCId"
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    value     = var.vpc_id
    resource  = "AWSEBSecurityGroup"
  }
```

and this one.

```
  setting {
    name      = "VPCId"
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    value     = var.vpc_id
    resource  = ""
  }
```

unfortunately without success, does anyone have an idea?

I am using Terraform version 0.14.11 and the AWS Provider in version 3.74.3

Comment: You can probably leave out the `resource` entirely judging by the documentation.

Comment: @MarkoE Thanks for your comment, but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you add output of `terraform plan` to the question?

Comment: I see few special conditions set for `resource` within `setting` block in provider [code](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/611b4737168f4f0051bb63ef221f0e76f156f392/internal/service/elasticbeanstalk/environment.go#L954-L959). Don't know what this means on AWS.